# Grouping items in a list into inner lists

Tags: java, performance, memory-optimization

I have a function that looks up in a `list` the elements which share same values in order to group them.

As a fast summary, this should be the input/output:

> [A, A', B, C, B', A''] --> [[A, A', A''], [B, B'], [C]]

I do not care about order. It could also produce:

> [A, A', B, C, B', A''] --> [[B, B'], [A, A', A''], [C]]

This is my test code to see the output samples:

> ```
> class A {
>   private Long id;
>   private String name;
>   private Object param;
>
>   A(Long id, String name, Object param) {
>     this.id = id;
>     this.name = name;
>     this.param = param;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public String toString() {
>     return "{\tid:" + id + ",\tname:" + name + ",\tparam:" + param + "}";
>   }
> }
>
> public class ListsTest {
>
>   private final A a1 = new A(1L, "A", 100);
>   private final A a2 = new A(2L, "B", 200);
>   private final A a3 = new A(1L, "A", 300);
>   private final A a4 = new A(1L, "B", 400);
>
>   @Test
>   public void groupByIdAndName() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
>     List<A> aList = List.of(a1, a2, a3, a4);
>     System.out.println("groupByIdAndName");
>     System.out.println("Input: ---> " + aList);
>     List<List<A>> aGroupedBy = Lists.groupByFields(aList, "id", "name");
>     System.out.println("Output: --> " + aGroupedBy);
>     System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
>     assertThat(aGroupedBy, is(List.of(List.of(a1, a3), List.of(a2), List.of(a4)))); 
>   }
>
>   @Test
>   public void groupById() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
>     List<A> aList = List.of(a1, a2, a3, a4);
>     System.out.println("groupById");
>     System.out.println("Input: ---> " + aList);
>     List<List<A>> aGroupedBy = Lists.groupByFields(aList, "id");
>     System.out.println("Output: --> " + aGroupedBy);
>     System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
>     assertThat(aGroupedBy, is(List.of(List.of(a1, a3, a4), List.of(a2))));
>   }
>
>   @Test
>   public void groupByName() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
>     List<A> aList = List.of(a1, a2, a3, a4);
>     System.out.println("groupByName");
>     System.out.println("Input: ---> " + aList);
>     List<List<A>> aGroupedBy = Lists.groupByFields(aList, "name");
>     System.out.println("Output: --> " + aGroupedBy);
>     System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
>     assertThat(aGroupedBy, is(List.of(List.of(a1, a3), List.of(a2, a4))));
>   }
> }
> ```

Which outputs:

> groupById
>
> Input: ---> [{    id:1,   name:A, param:100}, {   id:2,   name:B, param:200}, {   id:1,   name:A, param:300}, {   id:1,   name:B, param:400}]
>   Output: --> [[{ id:1,   name:A, param:100}, {   id:1,   name:A, param:300}], [{ id:2,   name:B, param:200}], [{ id:1,   name:B, param:400}]]
>
> Output: --> [[{   id:1,   name:A, param:100}, {   id:1,   name:A, param:300}, {   id:1,   name:B, param:400}], [{ id:2,   name:B, param:200}]]
>
> ---
>
> groupByIdAndName
>
> Input: ---> [{    id:1,   name:A, param:100}, {   id:2,   name:B, param:200}, {   id:1,   name:A, param:300}, {   id:1,   name:B, param:400}]
>
> Output: --> [[{   id:1,   name:A, param:100}, {   id:1,   name:A, param:300}], [{ id:2,   name:B, param:200}], [{ id:1,   name:B, param:400}]]
>
> ---
>
> groupByName
>
> Input: ---> [{    id:1,   name:A, param:100}, {   id:2,   name:B, param:200}, {   id:1,   name:A, param:300}, {   id:1,   name:B, param:400}]
>
> Output: --> [[{   id:1,   name:A, param:100}, {   id:1,   name:A, param:300}], [{ id:2,   name:B, param:200}, {   id:1,   name:B, param:400}]]
>
> ---

The code I developed for it is the following:

```
public class Lists {

  private static <T> Object getObjectFieldsHash(T obj, String... fields) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<Object> vals = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String field: fields) {
      Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
      f.setAccessible(true);
      vals.add(f.get(obj));
    }
    return Objects.hash(vals);
}

  public static <T> List<List<T>> groupByFields(List<T> objects, String... fields ) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>(); // Is it possible to create same type of original List instead of always ArrayList?
    Map<Object, Integer> indexes = new HashMap<>();
    for (T obj: objects) {
      Object hash = getObjectFieldsHash(obj, fields);
      indexes.computeIfAbsent(hash, (_unused) -> indexes.size()); // How can I remove _unused variable?
      Integer nextIndex = indexes.get(hash);
      if (nextIndex >= result.size()) { // Maybe I could use ==. Does it improve anything? 
        result.add(new ArrayList<T>()); // Is it possible to create same type of original List instead of always ArrayList?
      }
      result.get(nextIndex).add(obj);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to improve this?

I'm thinking of:

1. I can pass as argument any subtype of `List`, but I'm always returning `ArrayList`s.
2. I was forced to declare the `_unused` variable in my `lambda function`, or won't compile, producing error: "Cannot infer functional interface type".
3. Does using `==` instead of `>=` to check if I already created a sublist provide me any kind of improvement?
4. I named this method `groupByFields`, but I feel like is the opposite of "flatMap" kind functions. Is there any concept which gives me a more standarized method name?

Comment: Prefer method-references over reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` is easier to read than `obj`. `values` is easier to read than `vals`. Avoid unnecessary abbreviations.

Don’t give things misleading names. You’re calling something a `field` when it’s really a `fieldName`.

Using a `Map` in `groupByFields` is a good idea, but you’re making it a lot harder than it needs to be by sticking everything in a list right away. Just keep the hash as the key and a set of objects as the value.

There’s a good chance this is a big performance sink because of how much reflection you’re doing. Rather than reflect on every instance of every object, just do the reflection work once.

Your `getObjectsFieldHash` method is finding the has of a List of values, rather than on the actual values. Is that intentional?

To answer your questions,

> Is it possible to create same type of original List instead of always ArrayList?

Yes, but why? This method should be a lot more generic - it can handle arbitrary collections unless you need your grouping function to be stable. You should be doing most of your work behind the Collections API interfaces. If you really need a specific concrete type yourself, it's preferable to make that type and dump the existing collection into it via a constructor. That will copy all the members over.

> How can I remove _unused variable?

You can’t. `computeIfAbsent` requires a function that takes in a key.

> Maybe I could use ==. Does it improve anything?

It might affect performance in some trivial way, but you’re better off refactoring the code to be easier to read.

> Is it possible to create same type of original List instead of always ArrayList?

See above

So, if you're OK with using what I think are more appropriate collections than lists, you can try:

```
public static <T> Collection<Set<T>> groupByFields(
        final Class<T> objectClazz,
        final Collection<T> objects,
        final String... fieldNames)
                throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {

    final Field[] fields = fieldsFor(objectClazz, fieldNames);
    final Map<Integer, Set<T>> groupings = new HashMap<>();
    for (final T object : objects) {
        final int hash = hashOf(object, fields);
        groupings.computeIfAbsent(hash, k -> new HashSet<T>()).add(object);
    }

    return groupings.values();
}
```

If you feel strongly about lists, but don't have a really good reason to require specific list types, try:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> groupByFields(
        final List<T> objects,
        final String... fieldNames)
                throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {

    final Field[] fields = fieldsFor(objects.get(0).getClass(), fieldNames);
    final Map<Integer, List<T>> groupings = new HashMap<>();
    for (final T object : objects) {
        final int hash = hashOf(object, fields);
        groupings.computeIfAbsent(hash, k -> new ArrayList<T>()).add(object);
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(groupings.values());
}
```

And if you feel really strongly about controlling the types of lists being used, you can use:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> groupByFields(
        final Class<? extends List<T>> listClazz,
        final Class<? extends List<List<T>>> listOfListsClazz,
        final List<T> objects,
        final String... fieldNames)
                throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

    final Field[] fields = fieldsFor(objects.get(0).getClass(), fieldNames);
    final Map<Integer, List<T>> groupings = new HashMap<>();
    for (final T object : objects) {
        final int hash = hashOf(object, fields);
        groupings.computeIfAbsent(hash, k -> {
            try {
                return listClazz.newInstance();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot instantiate a new instance of " + listClazz.getCanonicalName());
            }
        })
        .add(object);

    }

    final List<List<T>> result = listOfListsClazz.newInstance();
    result.addAll(groupings.values());
    return result;
}
```

All three top-level methods use the same two helpers:

```
private static final <T> Field[] fieldsFor(final Class<T> clazz, final String[] fieldNames)
        throws NoSuchFieldException {

    final Field[] fields = new Field[fieldNames.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        final Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldNames[i]);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        fields[i] = field;
    }

    return fields;
}

private static final <T> Integer hashOf(final T object, final Field... fields)
        throws IllegalAccessException {

    final Object[] values = new Object[fields.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = fields[i].get(object);
    }
    return Objects.hash(values);
}
```

Finally, note that I do agree with `RobAu` that avoiding reflection would be better, but we don't have enough context to consider alternatives.